# STM32F100RBT6B usart data deformation

Tags: c, stm32

I have on radio transmitter and one radio receiver like on the picture. What I am trying to do.

I send data through USART2 **PA2** (**pin2**) on data transmitter. 
I connected usb-uart to **PA2** (**pin2**), and looked in terminal what data is there and I saw something like this (**11 22 33 44 11 22 33 44 11 22 33 44 11 22 33 44 11 22 33 44 11 22 33 44 11 22 33 44 11 22 33 44 11 22 33 44** ).It's okay i transmit what i want.

Then i connected usb-uart to **PA10** (**pin10**) radio receiver, and looked in terminal, there was a lot of data but mostly of them was (**44 FD 11 22 33 44 7F 10 22 33 44 FE 11 22 33 44 00 00 00 A4 26 F4 F8 11 22 33 44 FE 11 22 33 44 FA 10 22 33 44 FF 11 22 33 44 FE 11 22 33 44 D6 11 22 33 44** ).It's okay i receive from receiver module data that was transmitted and something else....

Then I connected usb-uart to **PA9** (**pin9**), and looked in terminal, there was only (**11 33 44 FC 11 33 44 FF 10 33 44 FF 11 33 44 FE** ).

When USART1 receiving data from transmitter(**Pin10**)(**44 FD 11 22 33 44 7F 10** ) it receiving full sequence(**11 22 33 44**), but when it transmit to Pin9 i see only (**11 33 44**) in usb-uart.

Where is one byte (**22**)? Where is error and why it's happening thanks!

The main question what I am doing wrong, why USART1 TX deformates data? Or what? How to fix this?

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"
#include "stm32f10x_gpio.h"
#include "stm32f10x_rcc.h"

#define SYNC 0xAA
#define RADDR 0x44
#define LEDON 0x11//switch led on command
#define LEDOFF 0x22//switch led off command

void Delay(uint32_t value)
{
    volatile uint32_t i;
    for (i = 0; i != value; i++)
        ;
}
void send_to_uart1(uint8_t data)  
    {
    while(!(USART1->SR & USART_SR_TC))
    {
    }
    USART1->DR=data;                
}

void send_to_uart2(uint8_t data)
{
    while (!(USART2->SR & USART_SR_TXE));
    USART2->DR = data;
}

uint8_t GetChar (void)  {
  while (!(USART1->SR & USART_SR_RXNE));
  return ((USART1->DR));
}
uint8_t uart_data;

int k=0;

char message[4]={0x11,0x22,0x33,0x44};

    int main(void)
    {
        GPIO_InitTypeDef PORTA_init_struct;

        RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOA | RCC_APB2Periph_USART1, ENABLE);
        RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_USART2, ENABLE);

        PORTA_init_struct.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_9;
        PORTA_init_struct.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_2MHz;
        PORTA_init_struct.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF_PP;
        GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &PORTA_init_struct);

        PORTA_init_struct.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_10;
        PORTA_init_struct.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_2MHz;
        PORTA_init_struct.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IN_FLOATING;
        GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &PORTA_init_struct);

        PORTA_init_struct.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_2;
        PORTA_init_struct.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_2MHz;
        PORTA_init_struct.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF_PP;
        GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &PORTA_init_struct);

        PORTA_init_struct.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_3;
        PORTA_init_struct.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_2MHz;
        PORTA_init_struct.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IN_FLOATING;
        GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &PORTA_init_struct);

        USART_InitTypeDef uart_struct1;
        uart_struct1.USART_BaudRate = 1200;
        uart_struct1.USART_WordLength = USART_WordLength_8b;
        uart_struct1.USART_StopBits = USART_StopBits_1;
        uart_struct1.USART_Parity = USART_Parity_No;
        uart_struct1.USART_HardwareFlowControl = USART_HardwareFlowControl_None;
        uart_struct1.USART_Mode = USART_Mode_Rx | USART_Mode_Tx;
        USART_Init(USART1, &uart_struct1);
        USART_Cmd(USART1, ENABLE);

        USART_InitTypeDef uart_struct2;
        uart_struct2.USART_BaudRate = 1200;
        uart_struct2.USART_WordLength = USART_WordLength_8b;
        uart_struct2.USART_StopBits = USART_StopBits_1;
        uart_struct2.USART_Parity = USART_Parity_No;
        uart_struct2.USART_HardwareFlowControl = USART_HardwareFlowControl_None;
        uart_struct2.USART_Mode = USART_Mode_Rx | USART_Mode_Tx;
        USART_Init(USART2, &uart_struct2);
        USART_Cmd(USART2, ENABLE);

        while (1) {
                while(k<4)
                {
                    for (int j=0;j<4;j++)
                    {
                        send_to_uart2(message[k]);
                        k=k+1;
                    }
                    for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
                    {
                        send_to_uart1(GetChar());
                    }
            }
            k=0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not even clear this is a software problem.

Comment: Why does `send_to_uart1()` use `& USART_SR_TC` and `send_to_uart2()` use `& USART_SR_TXE`?  Suspicious about `while (!(USART1->SR & USART_SR_RXNE));`

Comment: Perhaps the receive side buffer is overflowing?  Try a message of only 1 byte rather than 4.

Comment: @chux, messages that contains only 3 bytes, always come without loss.

Comment: I suspect your revive buffer cannot queue up so many bytes.  Try interlacing `for (int j=0;j<4;j++)
                    {
                        send_to_uart2(message[k]);
                        send_to_uart1(GetChar());
                        k=k+1;
                    }
                    for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
                    {
                    }` with the 4 byte message.

Comment: @chux, okay but if it possible communicate only with 3 bytes, how communicate when it's needed to send long messages 10-30 bytes?

Comment: With limited serial buffer sizes, code cannot spend all its time transmitting 30 bytes and _then later_ reading 30 bytes, but needs to sends a byte or 2, read what it can, and loop.  Code needs to interlace the various tasks.  Perhaps your serial driver can be configured for buffered reception? IDK.

Comment: @Olaf I believe it is software problem because you can see IRQ is not used for receive therefore he looses data when sends one. Do receive in IRQ.

Comment: @A191919  [tilz0R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44574972/stm32f100rbt6b-usart-data-deformation?noredirect=1#comment76142086_44574972) is the right approach.  Handle reception in a ISR (Interrupt service routine) and queue the incoming data.

Comment: @chux I don't see IRQ routine. `GetChar` function is doing polling for receive.

Comment: @tilz0R: There are too many variables and the question is way too unclear and confused. One definitive thing is the delay loop. This is plain broken by design. Not only there is no need for it, but it also can mess up timing. But - as I wrote: too little information. Btw.: polling is fine for a simple test. No need to add the complications of interrupt handlers.

Comment: @tilz0R Agreed,a interrupt routine, not yet coded, would help code handle input.  UNless OP wants to do a lot of polling.

Comment: @A191919 check hardware lines using logic analyzer to see who is the problem. According to the fact each second byte is missing, I believe you have problem with receive software.

Comment: @chux You cannot send and receive byte at the same time with polling on UART. You can expect missing bytes in that case.

Comment: @A191919 Look at the other bits in `USART2->SR` and see if any over-run or other errors are occurring.  Please report their status as it will provide greater insight to the issue.

Comment: @tilz0R [Disagree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44574972/stm32f100rbt6b-usart-data-deformation?noredirect=1#comment76142238_44574972) I have successful done so - it depends on what that polling does, latency and relative rates of polling versus transmit rates.

Comment: @chux, thanks for the advice!

Comment: @chux I believe it works but this is in general wrong approach and should not be recommended to even learn it.